# PHP Оборвать соединение с сервером

Tags: php

Не могу понять как сделать функцию для моментального разрыва соединения с сервером. Я читал что нужно использовать `ob_start(); ob_end_flush(); flush();` и т.д, но это нужно делать во всех местах где мне нужно при какой-то ошибке разорвать соединение, у меня таких мест более 15, и что, мне теперь в каждом месте поместить ещё по 15 строк повторяющегося кода? Можно ли сделать какую-то функции например `close_connection()`, именно функцию, чтоб при необходимости вызывать её и закрывать соединение, не давай делать `echo` в php дальше.

Comment: Ну так вам же нужен `exit`?

Comment: Вам нужно правильно проектировать приложение. Использовать классы, методы, исключения. Выстраивать их взаимодействие. У меня в коде нет ни одного вызова `exit` при это выводится только то, что должно

Comment: @And не помогает, я уже и через die, exit пытался, по всем примерам, все равно продолжает работу скрипт :(

Comment: @And аа, точно, спасибо

Comment: @ArchDemon, как минимум, после отправки заголовков нужно делать `exit` =)